# Declaring arrays in soy file

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am pretty new to Google closures.  I am not sure how to declare and assign values to arrays in Soy file (google Closure).
Please advise.

Comment: I've never modified or created data in a soy file. The typical pattern is to output content based on input data passed into a template.

Comment: I tried {let $<identifier>: <expression> /} but it works only for variables and not arrays

Comment: this compiles for me: {let $P : [1,2,3,4]/} -- compiles down to this:  var output = opt_sb || new soy.StringBuilder();
  var P__soy461 = [1, 2, 3, 4]; so it should work fine

Comment: @chad, yeah, i only found out about the let command recently as well, but it is pretty handy.

Comment: But when I try to iterate over the array like 
{let $ArrayName : [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] /}
{for $i in range(0, 7)}
{$ArrayName[$i]}
{/for}
This does not work

Comment: @lennel, Thanks got it  just had to add single quotes around the strings...

Answer (score 0):

just moving this to an answer for future reference:

this compiles for me: {let $P : [1,2,3,4]/} -- compiles down to this: var output = opt_sb || new soy.StringBuilder(); var P__soy461 = [1, 2, 3, 4]; so it should work fine